# Database driven CSS & fields - adv/disadv?

Tags: css, database-design, field

I am creating a user content website and not sure which is the better way to go with CSS - database driven or the default way? Also how to make the fields database driven so I can:
1) enforce max/min lengths from the db
2) ID each field so i can link them with which fields are on which page.

I am using MySQL and PHP. Thanks

Comment: How would the CSS be written to the page if it was DB driven?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out LessCSS -- http://lesscss.org/ -- using Less, you can add programmatic capability to CSS. Less can be used server-side or client-side. Based on your question, it might be appropriate to have DB-driven Less files emitted and processed server-side.